# Mule 3 CE - File Processing Order

Tags: java, mule, esb

Good morning to everybody, I have a problem using Mule ESB CE with file order. 
In the mule flow I have a File Inbound Endpoint that triggers the flow when one or more files come into a specified directory.

Let's assume that i have three files (a.txt,b.txt,c.txt), and I'd like to process b.txt first then a.txt and finally, c.txt.

How can I do that?

I read something about "File Processing Order" comparator that allows to write an own custom comparator but i did not find any example (neither in the Mule documentation).

Could anyone explain how to write a simple "file comparator" that order those files as above?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards
PL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement a custom comparator, and declare your file endpoint like this:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="fileConnector"
       path="${path}" 
       moveToDirectory="${move.path}"
       moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" 
       comparator="your.package.comparators.YourComparator"
/>
```

Note that I've had some classloading problems using custom comparators with file endpoints(at least on 3.3.1 CE), notably [this bug](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5979).

> Let's assume that i have three files (a.txt,b.txt,c.txt), and I'd like
>   to process b.txt first then a.txt and finally, c.txt.
>
> How can I do that?

As for the actual ordering, you need to use some [collation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html) to decide the order. This may be simple, or very complicated.

Comment: First of alla thank you reply. I would like to know how to build a simple comparator based on input file name.

Thank you a lot

Comment: @ParideLetizia take a loot at the link about collations in my answer.